# Chart.js multi line chart that has different labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two datasets A and B. Both A and B are timelines.

```
A=[{'time':'2020-11-20 00:00:00', "value":21},
   {'time':'2020-11-20 00:01:00', "value":22},
   {'time':'2020-11-20 00:02:00', "value":23},
   {'time':'2020-11-20 00:03:00', "value":24},]

B=[{'time':'2020-11-20 00:01:30', "value":21},
   {'time':'2020-11-20 00:03:30', "value":22},
   {'time':'2020-11-20 00:05:30', "value":24},]
```

Chart.js requires a single array with all labels, but my data doesn't share the same labels, although both are time series.

How can I use chart.js to plot this without changing the times/resampling?

Answer (score 0):

So  you have to create label first, which should be all time as explained below for A and B combined.
Now For A    {'time':'2020-11-20 00:00:00', "value":21},
{'time':'2020-11-20 00:01:00', "value":22},
then check this  principle.
For A  2020-11-20 00:00:30 value must be 21 only as nothing has been changed so assuming that you can create same number of labels for line and place values.

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
  var data = {
      labels: ["2020-11-20 00:00:00", "2020-11-20 00:30:00", "2020-11-20 01:00:00", "2020-11-20 01:30:00", "2020-11-20 02:00:00", "2020-11-20 02:30:00", "2020-11-20 03:00:00"],
      datasets: [
          {fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
           strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
           data: [21, 21, 22, 81, 56, 55, 40]
          },
          {fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
           strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
           data: [22, 23, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
          }
      ]};
```